# Is it fine to create array having values with key and no key?

Tags: php, arrays, key-value

I've an array in which most of the elements don't have keys.

```
$arr = array(
'element1',
'element2',
'key1' => 'element3',
'element4'
);
```

My question is, is it good practice to create array like this?
Or should i still create keys like this

```
$arr = array(
    'element1' => 'element1',
    'element2' => 'element2',
    'key1' => 'element3',
    'element4' => 'element4'
    );
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: They do have keys, they are just automatically generated from 0 and then up. - It doesn't really matter, it all depends on whether you need to have custom keys or if a incremented value is fine.

Comment: Depends on your goals. Keys are always uniqie (you cannot have two entries with the same key). Values can be anything. In PHP, the array is both an array and hashtable in one.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to create array without key. If you initialize array by this way:

```
$arrInit = array("Hi", "Hello");
print_r($arrInit);

//Output Array ( [0] => Hi [1] => Hello )
```

In above example, Initialize array `$arrInit` without declaration key but auto apply key from *0* to exist value. You can see the output.

But if you want to display that array without display key, follow below code:

```
print implode($arrInit, ',');
//Output Hi,Hello
```

Hope this help you well!